# access same class across two web service references in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, generics, types

I'm trying to create a C# class that can call the same methods on the same classes, but the classes can come from two different web service references.  I am accessing `SomeWebService` and `SomeWebServiceAlt`, where they have the same classes but are on different servers.  The goal is to be able to first try using the methods in `SomeWebService`, and if that one wigs out, to try `SomeWebServiceAlt`.  I was hoping to have some kind of generic class for accessing either web service, but I'm having trouble with type constraints because there aren't any common interfaces or base classes for the different classes I use from within either reference.  That is, I use `ConnectionClass` from both the `SomeWebService` namespace and the `SomeWebServiceAlt` namespace, but the two `ConnectionClass` classes are not seen as related by C#, so I can't just say `where TClass : CommonBaseClassAcrossWebServices`.  How should I do this?  I'm ending up repeating code and doing:

```
if (typeof(SomeWebService.ConnectionClass) == typeof(TConnection))
{ ... }
else if (typeof(SomeWebServiceAlt.ConnectionClass) == typeof(TConnection))
{ ... }
```

This seems really redundant and dirty.  I'm using .NET 3.5, and I don't have control over the two web services.  That's a difference between my question and similar questions I've seen on here:  other people had control of the web services.

I feel like my solution is going to end up using reflection to somehow check and see if an expected method exists, and then call that method on whichever web service's class I'm working with.

Comment: are you using WCF. if so look at sharing the objects in a DLL, then in the Contract of the app.config, make sure both services use the same DLL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they share the same service definition you can use the same reference, just change the host at runtime.

Comment: I don't know if I can guarantee they'll have the same service definition.  If I could though, how would I change the host at runtime?  In VS 2008, I have a Web Reference added to my Project, and that reference has the host URL.  That seems like a compile-time thing, as it is.

Comment: He's right. You don't need two web references or service references. Use one, and change the Url at runtime. If you've only got a single reference, you will, obviously, have only a single set of classes.

Comment: Found this tutorial:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx  Trying this now--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Web References, then  you're out of luck.

Use a Service Reference, and you can tell it to reuse the data types. You then have to ensure that your consuming application has access to the data types.

Comment: How could I convert a web reference to a service reference?

Comment: Don't convert it. Just use "Add Service Reference" and get rid of the web reference, and don't ever use them again.

Comment: I was able to dynamically change the web service reference URL at runtime, as suggested by Albin.  Is there a reason not to use web references?

Comment: Yes. Web References are the old ASMX technology. Microsoft now considers that to be "legacy technology". All new development should use WCF.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I kept coming back here.  I wanted to call a web service that could be named different on the client's side, different Service Name and different Service End Point, but the same contract underneath.  I did not need to dynamically determine anything, just call it from a different name/endpoint.  The answer is here but hard to understand.
1.  You should make this a Service Reference instead of a Web Reference, when you attach it to your project.  Attach just one version.
2.  At runtime, perhaps from the app settings, you can substitute the endpoint of the service with the endpoint of a service with the same contract, but different name.
                   svc2.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["client_service_endpoint"].ToString());

This will call the other web service, at the different endpoint, regardless of the Service Name.

Cheers!